# Exterior Product of 2-Forms in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, real-numbers, differential-forms

So I am studying the book of Arnold, *"Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics"* and I am trying to understand the differential forms.

The exterior product is defined for $1$-forms $ω_1$ and $ω_2$ as the $2$-form:
\begin{equation}
ω_1 \wedge ω_2 =
\begin{vmatrix}
  ω_1 & ω_2 \\
  ω_1 & ω_2
 \end{vmatrix}.
\end{equation}
By now I have studied the linear $- and $-forms. In particular, I would like to prove that every $2$-form $ω^2$ on the $n$-dimensional space with coordinates $x_1,...,x_n$ can be uniquely represented in the form:
\begin{equation}
ω^2=\sum_{i<j}α_{ij}x_i \wedge x_j
\end{equation}
A hint is given: Let $e_i$ be the $i$-th basis vector i.e. $x_i(e_i)=1, x_j(e_i)=0, i \neq j$. Then $ω^2(e_i,e_j)=α_{ij}$.

How can I prove that?

Comment: What is your definition of a $2$-form? To me it is (almost) *by definition* an expression of the form $\sum_{i<j}\alpha_{ij}x_i\wedge x_j$...

Comment: @Servaes Well it is not defined yet. It just defines the $\wedge$ and then asks of me to prove that in this coordinate system the $ω^2$ form has this expression.

Comment: Is a $2$-form defined to you as an element of $\Lambda^2(\Bbb{R}^n)^{\ast}$? (or $\Lambda^2(\Bbb{C}^n)^{\ast}$, or something similar?)

Comment: Well it is defined as an element of the dual space of an $n$-dimensional space. In this particular case I think he talks about $ \left( \mathbb{R}^n \right)^*$. But I am not sure what $Λ$ is in your comment :/

Comment: Ah great, so the $x_i$ are elements of $(\Bbb{R}^n)^{\ast}$? Then I'm curious how $\wedge$ is defined if $\Lambda$ is not defined. Could you include a definition in your question, for completeness' sake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are effectively asked to show that the $2$-forms $x_i\wedge x_j$ with $1\leq i<j\leq n$ form a basis for the vector space of all $2$-forms. It is instructive to verify that the set of all $2$-forms is indeed a (real) vector space. I'll first prove the fact without the hint, and later with the hint.

---

Let $\omega^2$ be a $2$-form. Then $\omega^2=\omega_1\wedge\omega_2$ for a pair of $1$-forms $\omega_1,\omega_2\in(\Bbb{R}^n)^{\ast}$. As you note, the coordinate functions $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in(\Bbb{R}^n)^{\ast}$ form a basis for $(\Bbb{R}^n)^{\ast}$, which means that
$$\omega_1=\sum_{i=1}^n\beta_i x_i\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\omega_2=\sum_{j=1}^n\gamma_j x_j,$$
for unique $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n,\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n\in\Bbb{R}$. It follows that for all $\xi_1,\xi_2\in\Bbb{R}^n$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\omega^2(\xi_1,\xi_2)
&=&\begin{vmatrix}
 \sum_{i=1}^n\beta_i x_i(\xi_1) & \sum_{j=1}^n\gamma_j x_j(\xi_1) \\
 \sum_{i=1}^n\beta_i x_i(\xi_2) & \sum_{j=1}^n\gamma_j x_j(\xi_2)
 \end{vmatrix}\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^n\beta_i x_i(\xi_1)\cdot\sum_{j=1}^n\gamma_j x_j(\xi_2)
-\sum_{i=1}^n\beta_i x_i(\xi_2)\sum_{j=1}^n\gamma_j x_j(\xi_1)\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_i\gamma_jx_i(\xi_1)x_j(\xi_2)-\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_i\gamma_jx_i(\xi_2)x_j(\xi_1).
\end{eqnarray*}
This seems like quite the mess, but we can group the terms by the factors $x_i(\xi_1)x_j(\xi_2)$ to get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(\beta_i\gamma_j-\beta_j\gamma_i)x_i(\xi_1)x_j(\xi_2).$$
By symmetry the coefficients of $x_i(\xi_1)x_j(\xi_2)$ and $x_j(\xi_1)x_i(\xi_2)$ differ only in sign, so this reduces to
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i<j}^n(\beta_i\gamma_j-\beta_j\gamma_i)(x_i(\xi_1)x_j(\xi_2)-x_j(\xi_1)x_i(\xi_2))
&=&\sum_{i<j}^n(\beta_i\gamma_j-\beta_j\gamma_i)
 \begin{vmatrix}
 x_i(\xi_1) & x_j(\xi_1)\\
 x_i(\xi_2) & x_j(\xi_2)
 \end{vmatrix}\\
&=&\sum_{i<j}^n(\beta_i\gamma_j-\beta_j\gamma_i)x_i\wedge x_j.
\end{eqnarray*}
So we see that $\alpha_{ij}=\beta_i\gamma_j-\beta_j\gamma_i$. And indeed
$$\omega^2(e_i,e_j)=
\begin{vmatrix}
 \sum_{k=1}^n\beta_k x_k(e_i) & \sum_{k=1}^n\gamma_k x_k(e_i) \\
 \sum_{k=1}^n\beta_k x_k(e_j) & \sum_{k=1}^n\gamma_k x_k(e_j)
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
 \beta_i & \gamma_i \\
 \beta_j & \gamma_j
\end{vmatrix}
=\beta_i\gamma_j-\beta_j\gamma_i=\alpha_{ij}
$$

---

With the hint there is a slicker proof as follows:

Let $\omega^2$ be a $2$-form, so that $\omega^2=\omega_1\wedge\omega_2$ for some $\omega_1,\omega_2\in(\Bbb{R}^n)^{\ast}$. Then
$$\omega^2:\ \Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{R}:
\ (\xi_1,\xi_2)\ \longmapsto\ \begin{vmatrix}
 \omega_1(\xi_1) &\omega_2(\xi_1)\\
 \omega_1(\xi_2) &\omega_2(\xi_2)
\end{vmatrix},$$
is an $\Bbb{R}$-bilinear map (verify this!). In particular, for any pair $(i,j)$ with $1\leq i<j\leq n$ the $2$-form $x_i\wedge x_j$ is $\Bbb{R}$-bilinear, and for all $1\leq a<b\leq n$ it satisfies
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x_i\wedge x_j)(e_a,e_b)
&=&
\begin{vmatrix}
 x_i(e_a) &x_j(e_a)\\
 x_i(e_b) &x_j(e_b)
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=&x_i(e_a)x_j(e_b)-x_i(e_b)x_j(e_a)\\
&=&\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1&\text{ if }a=i\text{ and }b=j\\
0&\text{ otherwise }
\end{array}
\right.,
\end{eqnarray*}
Now define $\alpha_{ij}:=\omega^2(e_i,e_j)$. Then the linear combination of bilinear maps
$$\sum_{i<j}\alpha_{ij}x_i\wedge x_j,$$
is again bilinear (verify this!), and for all pairs $(a,b)$ with $1\leq a<b\leq n$ it satisfies
$$\left(\sum_{i<j}\alpha_{ij}x_i\wedge x_j\right)(e_a,e_b)=\sum_{i<j}\alpha_{ij}(x_i\wedge x_j(e_a,e_b))=\alpha_{ab}=\omega^2(e_a,e_b).$$
Of course $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is a basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$, so the two bilinear maps agree on all pairs of basis vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n$. It follows that they agree everywhere, i.e. they are the same. So
$$\omega^2=\sum_{i<j}\alpha_{ij}x_i\wedge x_j.$$

Comment: Just beautiful. The book provides no proofs at all in order for me to get into this way of thinking for 1,2,...k-forms. But I have a question. You mention that $x_i(ξ_1)x_j(ξ_2)$ differ in sign. Is that due to the skew symmetry of the 2-forms? Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right!

Comment: Alright then! Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Tbh I prefer the proof without the hint :D

Comment: Shouldn't $\xi_1,\xi_2\in(\Bbb{R}^n)$ instead of $(\Bbb{R}^n)^{\ast}$? I mean, the tangent space instead of the cotagent space.

Comment: @LinconRibeiro You are right, I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So is this correct? First, let us assume that we talk about $\mathbb{R}^n$. By taking the standard basis $B={e_1,...,e_n}$, I then calculate the exterior product of $x_i, x_j$, the basic forms, element of the dual of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on this basis. I get:

\begin{equation}
(x_i \wedge x_j)(e_i,e_j)=
\begin{vmatrix}
 x_i(e_i) & x_j(e_i) \\
 x_i(e_j) & x_j(e_i)
 \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1
 \end{vmatrix}=1
\end{equation}
Now, one can easily prove that $(x_i \wedge x_i)$ is a 2-form that is:
\begin{equation}
ω^2=x_i \wedge x_j
\end{equation}
Therefore it holds that:
\begin{equation}
ω^2(e_i,e_j))=(x_i \wedge x_j)(e_i,e_j)=1
\end{equation}
Since the set of all $x_i$ 1-forms is a dual basis for $\left( \mathbb{R}^n \right)^*$ we can deduce that $\forall ω\in (\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ it holds:
\begin{equation}
ω=\sum_{i=1}^nα_ix_i
\end{equation}
If it holds for every $ω$ then it holds for $ω^2$ which is billinear and skew symmetric. Therefore:
\begin{equation}
ω^2=\sum_{i<j}a_{ij}x_i\wedge x_j
\end{equation}
I think I am missing something.

Comment: You are indeed missing an important fact. I'll type up an answer.